# Image Slide Calculation (position,index,which..)

Tags: javascript

**Goal**

Create a responsive slide for low ram devices.(immagine a set of many images at high resolution.. mobile device would crash).i want to show only one image and preload N images.

**Scenario**

Let's say i have 77 images (`nI=77`,variable).
Obiovsly i want to load the first image, but also want to preload 2 images per side (`nP=2`,variable).
That is a total of 5 boxes ( center, 2left, 2right ).`nB=nP*2+1`.

On init i want to disply the boxes/images as follows(the number is the image index)

```
[75][76][0][1][2]
```

0, the first image is atm the only visible image.

Now comes the tricky part.

If i press `<` (next) the static visualizzation is:

```
[76][0][1][2][3]
```

but every box moves! so if we start with a default position set:

```
[75][76][0][1][2]//image index
[ 0][ 1][2][3][4]//box index
[-2][-1][0][1][2]//box position
```

`<`

```
[76][0][1][2][ 3]//image index
[ 1][2][3][4][ 0]//box index
[-2][-1][0][1][2]//box position
```

Pressing left loads the the following image into the first box, moves the first box into the last position, every other box moves (one offsetwidth) to the left.

`>`

```
[74][75][76][0][1]//image index
[4][ 0][ 1][2][3]//box index
[-2][-1][0][1][2]//box position
```

Pressing right loads the the preceding image into the last box, moves the last box into the first position, every other box moves (one offsetwidth) to the right.

**Some relevant js**

```
var I=ARRAYOFIMAGES,
    nI=images.length,
    nP=2,
    nB=nP*2+1,
    nC=0,
    slideWidth=slide.offsetWidth; // CURRENT IMAGE INDEX 200px variable

function defaultPos(a,b){//[-400, -200, 0, 200, 400] 
 for(a=[],b=0;b<nB;b++){
  a[b]=(b-nP)*slideWidth
 }
 return a
}
function currentInd(a,b){//[75, 76, 0, 1, 2] 
 for(b=[],a=0;a<nB;a++){
  b[a]=(a+nC-nP+nI)%nI
 }
 return b
}
function next(e){
 nC=++nC%nI;
 d=1; // direction 
 calculate()
}
function prev(e){
 nC=(--nC+nI)%nI;
 d=0;
 calculate()
}
function calculate(){
 //for(BOXES){
 // if(ISIMAGE2CHANGE){box[l].style.backgroundImage='url('+I[IMAGEINDEX]+')')}
 // box[l].style.webkitTransform='translate3d('+POSITION+'px'+',0,0)';
 //}
}
```

**Partially working DEMO**

First Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/VfYR4/

New Demo (shorter but not loading proper image)

http://jsfiddle.net/7Nedw/1/

*Note: adjust the delay to `-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1000ms ease 1000ms;` to see what is going on.*

**Problem**

The math is wrong. if the index is 0 and i move backwards the positions and indexes are messed up.

the function returns the wrong index to load,position and in which box to load.

Comment: I have done the same work. I am preloading 4 images, first is the one which is showing to the user, two images right of it. and one image is left of it. If you want to do same, Let me know.

Comment: nice but i want to be able to control the amount of images i preload per side.also on each side i want to preload the same amount of images.

Answer (score 0):

Give your HTML markup like this

```
 <img src="" data-src="images/1.jpg" alt="img0"/>
 <img src="" data-src="images/2.jpg" alt="img1"/>
 <img src="" data-src="images/3.jpg" alt="img2"/>
 <img src="" data-src="images/4.jpg" alt="img3"/>
```

And use this method, when you will press your left or right button:

```
function preLoadImages() {
        var $image = $(".my-image");
        var $imageUnloaded = $(".my-image[src='']");

        for(var i=current;i<current+4;i++) {    //(current+1) is image index shown to user
            var j = (i+$image.length)%$image.length;
            console.log("Image to be loaded : "+j);
            var $this  = $($image[j]);
            if($this.attr('src') == '') {
                $this.attr('src',$this.data('src'));
            }
        }
    }
```

You can change the logic slightly if you want to change the number of preload images on each side.

Comment: I appreciate you help, but this does not solve my problem. btw pls no jquery and i don't want to change the markup or add useless vars.